# Why is Code Assist throwing a transforms-python:runVersions Error in Foundry Code Repo?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

In my Code Repo with an imported library my Code Assist is not loading properly. It is giving me a `transforms-python:runVersions` error. Also getting the problem `nothing provides openssl 1.0.2d needed by python-2.7.11-0`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code Assist breaks because of Python version conflict (e.g.: the imported custom library uses Python 3.6 but the consuming Python notebook uses Python 3.8). You’ll need to match Python versions, so you could either:

1. change the python version to 3.8 in your imported custom library (if you have access to the source code), rebuild and retag it and then use it in your consuming notebook or;
2. you could change your consuming Python notebook to use python 3.6 (instead of 3.8).

The solution is to match Python versions for both the imported library and consuming notebook.